# Network bottlenecks is concentrated on a specific host during query

Tags: performance, configuration

I have deployed a CoC version of PieCloudDB in a private cloud environment. My S3 service consists of a cluster of three machines. During the deployment of PieCloudDB database, I specified one of the machines as the S3 host. Now, during queries, I have discovered that the S3 network bottleneck is occurring on that particular host. How can I resolve this bottleneck issue?

Comment: For networking questions, try the [Network Engineering StackExchange](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com), or [StackOverflow](https://StackOverflow.com) since this seems to be AWS related.

Answer (score 0):

By creating an address mapping service, you can randomly forward requests to any of the S3 hosts for load balancing in PieCloudDB database.

1.Create a service where all the service ports are set to 9000

```
# cat minio_external.yaml 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: multi-external-service
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  clusterIPs:
  - None
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 9000
      targetPort: 9000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: multi-external-service
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: x.x.x.1  # Replace with your first s3 IP address
    ports:
      - port: 9000
  - addresses:
      - ip: x.x.x.2  # Replace with your second s3 IP address
    ports:
      - port: 9000
  - addresses:
      - ip: x.x.x.3  # Replace with your third s3 IP address
    ports:
      - port: 9000

# kubectl apply -f minio_external.yaml -n openpie-clusters
service/multi-external-service created
endpoints/multi-external-service configured
```

View the created service

```
# kubectl get endpoints -n openpie-clusters|grep multi-external-service
NAME                                           ENDPOINTS                                                AGE
multi-external-service                         x.x.x.1:9000,x.x.x.2:9000,x.x.x.3:9000                   3m30s
```

2.Modify the mapping for a specified virtual data warehouse

Modify the S3 endpoint in PCC

```
# kubectl get pcc -n  openpie-clusters  
NAME                           AGE
ac01h1tvsb0yrjgt1vpregb3d4bb   7d3h
cl01h29xva8bbgm74hcven4dycqc   30h

# kubectl edit pcc cl01h29xva8bbgm74hcven4dycqc  -n  openpie-clusters  
piecloudcluster.compute.openpie.com/cl01h29xva8bbgm74hcven4dycqc edited
```

Modify it to the following content:

```
s3endpoint: multi-external-service:9000
```

Restart the QE

```
# kubectl get sts -n  openpie-clusters
NAME                                   READY   AGE
pdb-qd-cl01h29xva8bbgm74hcven4dycqc    1/1     46h
pdb-qe-cl01h29xva8bbgm74hcven4dycqc    32/32   46h
pdb-uqd-ac01h1tvsb0yrjgt1vpregb3d4bb   1/1     7d19h

kubectl rollout restart sts/pdb-qe-cl01h29xva8bbgm74hcven4dycqc -n  openpie-clusters
```

3.Modify the global mapping

```
kubectl exec -it  postgres-7fdb968d4b-q4wnl  -n openpie-infra — bash
```

Modify the information in the field s3_endpoint of table t_pdb_instance in the dbpiebackend database to "multi-external-service:9000".

Modify the records in the deployment.

```
# kubectl edit secret s3-credential-secret -n openpie-connect
secret/s3-credential-secret edited
```

Modify the following item:

```
PDBCLUSTER_DATAS3ENDPOINT: bXVsdGktZXh0ZXJuYWwtc2VydmljZQ==
```

The value can be obtained through the following method.

```
# echo -n 'multi-external-service'|base64
bXVsdGktZXh0ZXJuYWwtc2VydmljZQ==
```

Restart the deployment

```
[root@host54 offline]# kubectl rollout restart deployment/infrastructure -n openpie-connect
deployment.apps/infrastructure restarted
```

Then S3 requests for creating a new virtual data warehouse will be mapped to different hosts.